# Border on merged cells disappears when downloading as Excel from Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, export-to-excel, cell-formatting

I've created a spreadsheet in Google Spreadsheet. The spreadsheet contains merged cells and I've placed a border around the merged cells.

When I choose download to Excel and open it in Excel it looses the border for all the merged cells except the first cell in the merged range.

Is there a solution to be found or a bug? If I select to download as ods format it keeps the border around the merged cells but loose background fill instead..

/Magnus

Answer (score 1):

I almost put a huge bounty on this question, but I figured it out (worked for me at least).

1. **Select all** the cells in the Google spreadsheet (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)
2. **Clear formatting**: Format > Clear formatting

Comment: That would solve the problem if it wouldn't force me to reformat every single sheet..

Answer (score 1):

### This solution works!

You need to select the table (or the cell where the border is missing) and right click and choose Table Formatting options. Then select *colors* and set the table border as `0.5` points (`pt`).

It appears that for some reason the table border width becomes `0 pt` and is not visible for merged cells. Setting the border width to something but zero, makes it visible again.

Comment: @Neuron Try this one. This should be an easy fix with least changes necessary.